# iOS Simulator (Xcode 4.2)

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have some code that reacts to orientation changes, and after a lot of debugging and frustration, I realized that although when testing on hardware my code works fine, when testing in simulator, although the simulator is landscape oriented, the code reads it's current orientation as portrait. Any reason for this? its frustrating.

Comment: Very simple reason for this. The simulator is not the hardware. Don't trust the simulator (any simulator) to be a 100% match for the hardware. There will always be differences, limitations, and other oddities no matter the platform.

Comment: Yea, whenever I'm testing orientation related stuff in the simulator I make sure I start in Portrait mode (on the simulator), for some reason even if you start in landscape it still registers as portrait :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the simulator you can make changes in 2 axis. at device in 3 axis.

You will get some interesting cases when you are debugging with a real device, which is highly recommended. You can get one around 100-200 USD (used).